# Conditional restructure a sortedDictionary (unionFind)

Tags: c#, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I made some C# code that outputs a `SortedDictionary <int index, list<int>values>>` Where the index always starts with lowest int of the list<> that follows. Here is a short example of input (in reality the input is larger):

```
index- Values<>
 2   - 2,3,6,7
 3   - 3,5
 5   - 5,7,9
11   - 11,12,12
```

Now I want to do some re-orderning in here. The values are linked indexes. I want to sort them so that connected indexes are grouped together, with no double indexes. That should result in output

```
 2 - 2,3,5,6,7,9
11 - 11,12
```

Initially i had problems working with a sortedDictionary using a foreach while also decreasing the dictionary set size. I solved that, and now give an update of this problem description with my latest code. It doesnt use a foreach anymore, and some sorting problems seam to be fixed now, but as a side effect it became pretty complex and large. And i doubt if it should be so complex, or might be written shorter, more simple.

Each List i call a **tree**, where is thoe dictionary are **trees**
And **Cursor** or **c** i use like reading out text digit by digit from screen.

For the moment I put it in a small concept function code in a console app. Just to check if it all works. Testing is quite complex, since number sets can be complexly linked. So its not directly visible if you got lots of sets and a lots of number how they should be sorted. Therefore manually checking code validity and results isn't easy either.

While I am not yet sure if it now indeed does work for 100%. It seams to work better then before. But i think this code is far from perfect, as i walk the set of trees twice. With a pre-sort and a final-sort.

```
            static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> NewSort(SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> trees)
    {
        bool debugmode = false;
        //pre sort
        List<int> indexTree = new List<int>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> tree in trees)
        {
            indexTree.Add(tree.Key);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < indexTree.Count; i++)
        {
            int cursor = 1;
            List<int> tree = new List<int>();
            int index = indexTree[i];
            tree = trees[index];
            while ((tree !=null)&& (cursor<tree.Count) )
            {
                int c = tree[cursor ];
                if (trees.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    if (trees[c] != null)
                    {
                        List<int> u = new List<int>();
                        u = trees[c];
                        tree.AddRange(u);
                        tree.Sort();
                        trees[index] = tree;
                        trees[c] = null;
                    }
                }
                cursor++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = trees.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int c = indexTree[i - 1];
            if (trees[c] == null)
            { trees.Remove(indexTree[i - 1]); }
            else
            {
                trees[c] = trees[c].Distinct().ToList();   //removing all duplicates
            }
        }
        indexTree = new List<int>();

        //resort.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> tree in trees)
        {
            indexTree.Add(tree.Key);
            if(debugmode) Console.WriteLine("* " +DumpIntList(trees[tree.Key]));
        }
        for (int i = (indexTree.Count); i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (debugmode) Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            List<int> tree = new List<int>();
            tree = trees[indexTree[i-1]];
            for (int j = 0; j < tree.Count; j++)
            {
                int c = tree[j];
                for (int k = (i - 2); k > 0; k--)
                {
                    List<int> compareTree = new List<int>();
                    compareTree = trees[indexTree[k]];
                    if (compareTree.IndexOf(c) != -1)   // found !
                    {
                        if (debugmode) Console.Write("found " + c.ToString() + " from ");
                        if (debugmode) Console.WriteLine(DumpIntList(tree) + " in (" + DumpIntList(compareTree)+ ")");
                        tree.Remove(c); // or we would create a duplicate
                        compareTree.AddRange(tree);
                        compareTree = compareTree.Distinct().ToList(); //removing doubles again, doubles as side effect of merging
                        compareTree.Sort();
                        trees.Remove(indexTree[i - 1]);
                        trees[indexTree[k]] = compareTree;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return trees;
    }
```

Maybe what i try to do inst that clear to some, what i try to do here is that i try to look if series have overlapping numbers, and if so merge them.
Where each series is always sorted and starts with the lowest number of that series. As I found recently this might be a version of the **UnionFind** problem. The problem also appears in Blob detection, and finding what web pages are link eachother in a set of webpages. (but my data is a strange set lab measurements).

The difficulty is that there are lots of series, and it might be not directly clear if they are connected

```
1-3-4
4-7-9
11-12
would result in 2 series :
1) 1-3-4-7-9
2) 11-12
But after you add series 12-3 then it would all become one series.
```

Some more test data :

```
 2 - 2,3,5,6,7           // note my data is always ordered like this
 5 - 5,7,9               // dictionary starts with lowest key
11 - 11,12,12,27,30,31   // each list inside a tree key 
22 - 22,27               // is ordered low to high
23 - 23,25               // lowest int, equals the dict key.
28 - 28,30
34 - 34
```

Output using above function

```
 2 - 2,3,5,6,7,9
11 - 11,12,22,27,28,30,31
23 - 23,25
34 - 34
```

So while the code seams to work now, I highly doubt its ideal code, i irritate the trees set twice. And so i wonder if better solutions are possible. It might also be that the code doesnt do what i hope it todo; as i'm still testing it.

Comment: just was updating the questing while you asked :)

Comment: are you trying to avoid using linq?

Comment: Well i'm not realy sure about using linq would made the code run faster.
As i dont have much experience with it either. I kept my solving in area in terms that i can read and write easily (although i get writing problems like these). But if there is some magic linq code that solves it fast i'm all ears.

Comment: Ok .. just let me know .. what is `the logic of compress`? means if you have 10 sorted node .. then how many will be there in `result set`

Comment: Linq doesnt make things faster. Linq is just regular code wrapped up in shiny methods to make things more readable. It gives you the power to do alot with "oneliners".

Comment: updated question with new code that seams to work, but which also seams to be far from ideal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i decreased the size of the function and improved it.
It should now be a single irritation over all trees.
Unless someone knows a better answer, i think its "the" answer.
The code has been tested to work with larger sets, and i couldnt spot errors.

```
    static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> NewSort(SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> trees)
    {
        bool debugmode = false;
        //pre sort
        List<int> indexTree = new List<int>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> tree in trees)
        {
            indexTree.Add(tree.Key);
            if(debugmode) Console.WriteLine("* " +DumpIntList(trees[tree.Key]));
        }
        for (int i = (indexTree.Count); i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (debugmode) Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            List<int> tree = new List<int>();
            tree = trees[indexTree[i-1]];
            for (int j = 0; j < tree.Count; j++)
            {
                int c = tree[j];
                for (int k = (i - 2); k > -1; k--)      // k can be 0 but i can minimally be 1
                {
                    List<int> compareTree = new List<int>();
                    compareTree = trees[indexTree[k]];  // for loop > checking all trees
                    if (compareTree.IndexOf(c) != -1)   // found !
                    {
                        if (debugmode) Console.Write("found " + c.ToString() + " from ");
                        if (debugmode) Console.WriteLine(DumpIntList(tree) + " in (" + DumpIntList(compareTree)+ ")");
                      //  tree.Remove(c);               // or we would create a duplicate
                        compareTree.AddRange(tree);
                        compareTree = compareTree.Distinct().ToList();

                        compareTree.Sort();
                        trees.Remove(indexTree[i - 1]);
                        trees[indexTree[k]] = compareTree;
                        j =tree.Count;                  //break from more checks. maybe dirty code but it increases speed
                        break;                          //break checking loop on all trees for current tree
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return trees;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than inverting an if to avoid 1 level of nesting, I don't yet see how `LINQ` can be used to improve the readability of this code block.

```
        static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> SortTree(SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> trees)
        {
            //SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> newtrees = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();

            if (trees.Count < 2) { return trees; }  // dont process if ntrees contains 1 or 0 trees

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> singletree in trees)
            {
                int cursor = 1;
                bool nFinish = false;
                List<int> n = singletree.Value;
                if (n.Count <= 1) continue;
                while (nFinish == false)
                {
                    if (trees.ContainsKey(n[cursor]))
                    {
                        List<int> t = trees[n[cursor]];   // think of a screen cursor going over the list table
                        t.AddRange(n);
                        trees.Remove(n[cursor]);
                        n.Sort();
                        trees[singletree.Key] = n;
                    }
                    cursor++;
                    if (cursor != n.Count) continue;
                    nFinish = true;
                }
            }
            return trees;
        }
```

Comment: it wasnt about that it needed to be converted to Linq, it mainly didnt work as one cannt irritate using foreach and at the same time delete items from that for-each set despite (to be skipped and removed) that it is what i wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your **solution** with `test cases`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> tempRepositary = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();

            //test 1
            tempRepositary.Add(2, new List<int>(new[] { 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 }));
            tempRepositary.Add(5, new List<int>(new[] { 5, 7, 9 }));
            tempRepositary.Add(11, new List<int>(new[] { 11, 12, 12, 27, 30, 31 }));
            tempRepositary.Add(22, new List<int>(new[] { 22, 27 }));
            tempRepositary.Add(23, new List<int>(new[] { 23, 25 }));
            tempRepositary.Add(28, new List<int>(new[] { 28, 30 }));
            tempRepositary.Add(34, new List<int>(new[] { 34 }));

            //test 2
            //tempRepositary.Add(2, new List<int>(new[] { 2,3,6,7 }));
            //tempRepositary.Add(3, new List<int>(new[] { 3,5 }));
            //tempRepositary.Add(5, new List<int>(new[] { 5,7,9 }));
            //tempRepositary.Add(11, new List<int>(new[] { 11,12,12 }));

            var refreshOne = SortTree(tempRepositary);    

            foreach (var item in refreshOne)
            {
                Console.Write("Key:" + item.Key + " ");
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item.Value));                 
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> SortTree(SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> trees)
        {
            if (trees.Count < 2) { return trees; }  // dont process if ntrees contains 1 or 0 trees

            SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> compressedTree
                = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();

            var allKeys = trees.Keys.ToList();
            var allValues = trees.Values.ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < allKeys.Count; i++)
            {
                var tempValues = allValues[i];
                var tempMax = tempValues.Max();

                for (int j = i + 1; j < allKeys.Count; )
                {
                    if (tempMax >= allKeys[j])
                    {
                        tempValues.AddRange(allValues[j]);
                        allKeys.Remove(allKeys[j]);
                        allValues.Remove(allValues[j]);
                        //
                        tempMax = tempValues.Max();
                        continue;
                    }
                    j++;
                }

                compressedTree.Add(allKeys[i], tempValues.Distinct().OrderBy(i1 => i1).ToList());
            }

            return compressedTree;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will test it (next week i can code again), i was also thinking, to instead of deleting a key-value pairs; assign them a speciall value.A Null or even a real zero, or a negative value. 
As the sets never contain such values my foreach would work, and then later it could be removed such KVP's. But i'll also check your answer. As while tampering with code i noticed sometimes not all series connections are updated and it needs to work on a larger set then the sample in the code. 
Sets with of a lot of fractions (lots of connected smaller sets) tend to be problematic.

Comment: it doesnt seam to work  2-3-5-6-7  and 5-7-9 and 11-12-12 are all merged to one 2-3-5-6-7-9-12  While 11-12 isnt conected to the number range

Comment: what  `int CompressRatio = ?;` .. you provided .. @user3800527

Comment: i gave a small update in the end of how the problem behaves. see above text

Comment: what is the scenario??

Comment: I need to group together indexes that belong to eachother.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105694/discussion-between-moumit-and-user3800527).